# Ng enter and leave not working when applied to custom css class

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate

I'm working with ngAnimate to show animations on screen transitions in my angular app. We are using ui-router.

What I want is to have the login screen slide upwards off the screen to reveal the next screen, after the user logs in successfully. How can I apply the .ng-leave class to only the login screen?

Here's the useful code I've got so far:

login-directive.html:

```
<div class="login-slide" id="login-slide">
<div class="viewport-1">
    <header></header>
    <background></background>
    <login-form callLogin="login(username, password)"></login-form>
    <version-footer></version-footer>
</div>
```

styles.css:

```
    @keyframes slideOutUp {
    0% {
      transform: translate(0px, 400px);
    } 

    100% {
      transform: translate(0, -600px);
    }    
  }

  .login-slide.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation: slideOutUp 3s ease;
    -moz-animation: slideOutUp 3s ease;
    -o-animation: slideOutUp 3s ease;
    animation: slideOutUp 3s ease;
  }

  #login-slide.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation: slideOutUp 3s ease;
    -moz-animation: slideOutUp 3s ease;
    -o-animation: slideOutUp 3s ease;
    animation: slideOutUp 3s ease;
  }
```

From everything I've seen, this should be enough to get the login-slide class to "slide" away when the login is complete because the login screen would be leaving the DOM at that time.

I'm also very open to using a combo of ng-class, ng-if, or any other directives if that would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1) You need to use some type of angular directive on the element you're trying to animate. In this case it looks like `ng-view` would be your best option since you're using ui-router. [Here's a good example.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

2) `.ng-leave` is the state of the element at the *start* of the animation. You need to have its finished state as well: `.ng-leave-active`. (Also in the example above)

Hope that helps.